# Set of irreducible non-isomorphic tensor products of representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, $\pi: G\to H$ be some surjective homomorphism.

Let also $\{\rho_i\} _{i\in I}$ be the full set of all 1-dimensional representations (up to iso) of $G$ and $\{\delta_j\} _{j\in J}$ be the full set of all irreducible representations of $H$.

Using $\pi$, we can define tensor product of these representations:
$$\rho_i\otimes (\delta_j \circ \pi): G\to GL(V) $$

Composition of irreducible with epimorphism is again irreducible, tensor product of irreducible with 1-dimensional is also irreducible, so these products are irreducible.

But there is no guarantee that $\rho_{i_1}\otimes (\delta_{j_1}\circ \pi)$ and $\rho_{i_2}\otimes (\delta_{j_2}\circ\pi)$ won't be isomorphic for different pairs of indices. Is there a way to find all non-isomorphic representations of such form or at least to count them?